# How to use the function `rsimsum` in R to do a simulation of a hypothesis test?

Tags: r, simulation

I try to use the function `rsimsum` in R to do a simulation of a hypothesis test and report the Monte Carlo standard error of the power. Assume that iid random sample $X_i\sim Bernoulli(\pi)$ for $i=1,\dots, 100$ and sample size is 100. We want to do a hypothesis test that
$$
H_0: \pi\ge 0.6,\, H_a: \pi<0.6
$$

As in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsimsum/vignettes/A-introduction.html, we have
$\hat{\pi}=\bar{X}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i.
$

Question 1: How to use `rsimsum` to compute MC error for this test?

Question 2: I have a question about the power of a significance test at the $\alpha=0.05$ level. In general definition, it is defined as $Power=P(reject \, H_0|H_a \mbox{is true})$. But why does it say that
$$
Power=\frac{1}{n_{sim}}\sum_{i=1}^{n_{sim}}I[|\hat{\pi}_i|>Z_{\alpha/2} \times \sqrt{\hat{Var}(\hat{\theta}_i)}]
$$
where $\sqrt{\hat{Var}(\hat{\theta}_i)}=\sqrt{\hat{Var}(\bar{X}_n)}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\hat{\pi}(1-\hat{\pi})}$.

Can we get the following figure for the relation of $\pi$ and power (resp. type I error)?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP8ZH.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the theory. Question 2 asks: Why doesn't the true parameter $\theta_a$ under the alternative hypothesis $H_a$ make an appearance in the formula for the power?

Let's assume we have a method to compute an estimator $\widehat{\theta}$ and its standard error $\sqrt{\widehat{\text{Var}}(\widehat{\theta})}$ from a dataset. Given $\widehat{\theta}$ and its SE we can do hypothesis testing: compute a p-value and a confidence interval and decide whether to reject or not reject the null hypothesis.

In a simulation study we generate many datasets and repeat the analysis for each dataset. In the $i$th simulation:

$$
\widehat{\theta}_i \pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\widehat{\text{Var}}(\widehat{\theta}_i)}
$$
is a $(1-\alpha)$100% confidence interval for the parameter $\theta$.

Furthermore, we reject the null hypothesis $H_0$ at the $\alpha$ significance level if $\theta_0$ is outside the $(1-\alpha)$100% confidence interval. Otherwise we don't reject the null. Note that this is a yes-or-no decision.

We record our reject/don't reject decision for each simulation. The proportion of rejections is an estimate of the power *P*.

$$
\widehat{P} = \frac{1}{n_{sim}} \sum_{i=1}^{n_{sim}} \mathbb{I}\left\{ \theta_0 \notin \left[ \widehat{\theta}_i \pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\widehat{\text{Var}}(\widehat{\theta}_i)} \right] \right\}
$$

And since this estimate of power is a proportion (of rejections) in a set of events (simulations), its Monte Carlo standard error has the form:

$$
\text{MCSE}(\widehat{P}) = \sqrt{\widehat{P}\left(1 - \widehat{P}\right) / n_{sim}}
$$

Now let's do a simulation study to estimate the power of the Wald test to test the null hypothesis $H_0: \pi = 0.6$ vs the alternative hypothesis $H_a: \pi \neq 0.6$.

*Notes*: 1. The Wald test is not the most powerful test for proportions. 2. You asked for the one-sided alternative $\pi < 0.6$ but, if I read the documentation correctly, *simsum* assumes a two-sided test. 3. So we will compute the one-sided power ourselves!

```r
library("rsimsum")
library("tidyverse")

set.seed(1234)

pi0 <- 0.6 # null hypothesis
pi1 <- 0.5 # alternative hypothesis

delta <- pi1 - pi0
sigma <- sqrt(pi1 * (1 - pi1))

# To be sure we know how to do a simulation study with rsimsum,
# let's find out the sample size necessary to achieve 90% power
alpha <- 0.05
power <- 0.9
za <- qnorm(1 - alpha / 2)
zb <- qnorm(power)

delta <- pi1 - pi0
sigma <- sqrt(pi1 * (1 - pi1))

# (Approximate) Sample size to achieve specified power at significance alpha
n <- ((za + zb) * sigma / delta)^2
n <- ceiling(n)
n
#> [1] 263

# We'll do lots of simulations
reps <- 1000

data <-
  crossing(
    dataset = seq(reps),
    n = seq(n)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    # Simulate data
    x = rbinom(n(), size = 1, prob = pi1)
  ) %>%
  group_by(
    dataset
  ) %>%
  group_modify(
    ~ summarise(.x,
      n = n(),
      # Compute estimator
      xbar = mean(x),
      # Compute its standard error
      se = sqrt(xbar * (1 - xbar) / n)
    )
  )
data
#> # A tibble: 1,000 × 4
#> # Groups:   dataset [1,000]
#>    dataset     n  xbar     se
#>      <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1       1   263 0.498 0.0308
#>  2       2   263 0.548 0.0307
#>  3       3   263 0.521 0.0308
#>  4       4   263 0.498 0.0308
#>  5       5   263 0.468 0.0308
#>  6       6   263 0.464 0.0308
#>  7       7   263 0.475 0.0308
#>  8       8   263 0.513 0.0308
#>  9       9   263 0.521 0.0308
#> 10      10   263 0.532 0.0308
#> # … with 990 more rows

s <- simsum(
  data = data,
  estvarname = "xbar", se = "se", true = pi1,
  by = c("n")
)
tidy(s, stats = c("thetamean", "bias", "cover", "power"))
#>        stat           est         mcse   n
#> 1 thetamean  0.4997110266           NA 263
#> 2      bias -0.0002889734 0.0009306672 263
#> 3     cover  0.9570000000 0.0064149045 263
#> 4     power  1.0000000000 0.0000000000 263
```

The estimate $\widehat{\theta}$ is correct, the coverage $1-\alpha$ is correct and *simsum* reports the power is 100%. However, we know that the power is 90%.

The issue is that *simsum* assumes the null hypothesis is $\theta = 0$. To see this, study the formula for the power in your question. And also note while *simsum* takes an argument *true* for the true value of the parameter, there is no argument for the null value.

Let's account for this by subtracting $\pi_0$ both from the estimators $\bar{x}$ and from the *true* value $\pi_1$.

```r
s <- simsum(
  data = data %>% mutate(xbar = xbar - pi0),
  estvarname = "xbar", se = "se", true = pi1 - pi0,
  by = c("n")
)
tidy(s, stats = c("thetamean", "bias", "cover", "power"))
#>        stat           est         mcse   n
#> 1 thetamean -0.1002889734           NA 263
#> 2      bias -0.0002889734 0.0009306672 263
#> 3     cover  0.9570000000 0.0064149045 263
#> 4     power  0.8970000000 0.0096120237 263
```

Now we get that the power is 90% as expected.

Finally, we can work around the limitations of *simsum* to show that the power for the one-sided hypothesis $H_a: \pi < 0.6$ is 96%. This also confirms we understand how to estimate the Monte Carlo standard error of the power.

```r
data %>%
  mutate(
    upper_limit = xbar + qnorm(1 - alpha) * se
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(
    power = mean(pi0 > upper_limit)
  )
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   power
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  0.96
```

Comment: Thanks. But the true $\pi$ is unknown, so when we do replication, we need to take some values of $\pi=0.8, 0.81, 0.82, \dots, 0.88$. Can we get a relation between $\pi$ and power function (resp. type I error)?

Comment: In the code, why `pi1 <- 0.65 # alternative hypothesis` not `pi1<-0.55`? since we need `\pi<0.6`?

Comment: It's a simulation, so it's easy to estimate power as a function of the true $\pi$: enclose the simulation in one big loop and vary $\pi$ in small increments; keep a record of the power estimate and its MCSE, so that you can make the plot. As the difference between $\pi_0$ and $\pi$ increases, the power also increases (with the type I error $\alpha$ and the sample size both fixed). // And yes it would have made more sense to pick $\pi = 0.55$ for a "less than" alternative. Sorry about that. The code is reproducible, so change $\pi$ and run the simulation again.

Comment: Can you see my figure? How to plot this similar graph in R?

Comment: The true parameter is always unknown; otherwise there won't be a need for a study in the first place. It's important to estimate power for realistic values for the true $\pi$. Often a reasonable range for $\pi$ is known from previous/related study or domain knowledge.

Comment: If we take lots of values of $\pi$, is there an easy way to plot the graph of power and $\pi$? It seems that changing another pi value is ok for two or three. But if we want to plot a graph, we need some different values.

Comment: This plot doesn't necessarily make sense to me. Why does the type I error vary? Anyway, the type I error is called `alpha` in the code. You can vary alpha and repeat the simulation. It is a coding exercise at this point. If you want to know how to do loops efficiently in R or something like that, it's a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: How about the first plot? the plot of pi and power.

Comment: I've shown how to do one simulation study. Making the plot is now all about repeating the simulation by varying the settings: $\pi$, $n$, etc. This makes it a programming question that's better suited to Stack Overflow. (But first make sure you understand how one simulation study works.) Or if you have another statistics question (eg, what the plot of type I error against $\pi$ shows), then it's better to make a new stand-alone CV post.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Can I ask if we can fix the sample size 100? It seems that you take a new sample size for a fixed power.

Comment: This is a programming question..... [& the last programming question I'm going to answer. It's important to understand what this code is doing, so I suggest you study it perhaps line by line until you do.] // Replace the lines *n <- ((za + zb) * sigma / delta)^2; n <- ceiling(n)* with *n = 100*.